# Mapserver 6.2 and deprecated st_Force_2D

Tags: postgresql, postgis, mapserver

On the PostgreSQL (9.3.0) + postGIS (2.1.0) side, I'm receiving the following WARNING log:

```
CONTEXT:  SQL function "st_force_2d" during startup
WARNING:  ST_Force_2d signature was deprecated in 2.1.0. Please use ST_Force2D
```

I found that the reason is the mapserver (6.2.1) layer used in the mapfile quering postgis data.

Do you know if in mapserver 6.4.0 (just released a week ago) the issue is resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was not addressed in 6.4.0. Opening an issue on the MapServer issue tracker would be a good start to get this added into a future release.